# SplitViewController Template show the popover manually?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, show

I am using the splitViewController template provided by Apple. On a specific action, I want to show the `rootViewController`. Unfortunately, I cannot find a method that will show the popover (programmatically) just as it does when you tap the bar button item.

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can show the popover from a `barButtonItem` or with your own rect with these two methods:

```
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect) inView:(UIView *) permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection) animated:(BOOL)];
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *) permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection) animated:(BOOL)]
```

`self.popoverController` is my case an ivar which stores the popover. I'm setting this variable each time in:

```
- splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:
```

and set it back to `nil` in it's counterpart method:

```
- splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem:
```

heres my code:

```
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc {
    barButtonItem.title = @"42";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
    self.popoverController = pc;
}

- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.popoverController = nil;
}
```

Comment: then use the `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:` method. You have to forward the bar button (which you also have to save in a variable or go through the view elements to find your need). And the arrow direction would be in this case upwards. [it is not a custom view it is the rect from which it will pop out. here it would be the rect of your bar button]

Comment: Okay, I did put in the viewDidAppear method; the popover is shown but the data in my tableView is not loaded. I guess that is because the method is called before the data is loaded?

Comment: I'm sure you will get it sooner or later. If not, just ask another question with your new problem. You can `NSLog()` your `rootViewController` to check if it's even loaded at all.

Comment: this works fine for me in viewDidAppear: `[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:[[self.toolbar items] objectAtIndex:0] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];`

Comment: yep it does. maybe because I have static data, so there is something with your data loading

Comment: Yeah, you may be right, I am loading data of the documents directory. I guess the viewdidAppear is fired before the data is loaded. Any idea how to prevent that?

Comment: fetch the data and call a delegate when ready, then reload the table view. (a bit more uglier you can call reload data after a second, this is more for debugging purposes than release software). Again I'm suggesting to open a new question if you have still problems. It is better to have the problem separated into smaller peaces than a large one. Maybe a part will help someone else ;)